# How to show elevation on mouse hover in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem, elevation

I need to show elevation of a DEM on the bottom bar (or wherever) on mouse hover in ArcMap 10.2.2. Is it possible?

I know I can access to it by opening "Identity", but that is not practical. It would be better to have information of it without clicking.

Comment: `I need to show elevation of a DEM on the bottom bar (or wherever) on mouse hover in ArcMap 10.2.2. Is it possible?` You seem to answer your own question when you say `I know I can access to it by opening "Identity`.  please edit your question to say where would be practicable other than the bottom bar.  Are you trying to achieve this through coding?  What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour].  By "DEM" are you referring to a raster layer or something else?

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for the link.

DEM = Digital Elevation Model, layer with XYZ values, raster layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on MapTips on your DEM layer.  If it is a Vector layer you can select which field to display e.g. `Elevation`.  If it is a Raster layer it will display the pixel value.

Right=click the layer and select Properties, and click on the Display tab.  Check the Show MapTips box, and OK to close.

[image]

Mouse over your layer, it will display a tooltip with the pixel value or value from the specified field.

[image]

Comment: Done that, but it is not showing the value after hovering mouse over the layer.

DEM is a GeoTiff format, maybe it is the problem?